# Object/factory with type NavigationService is not registered inside GetIt

Tags: flutter, dart, flutter-navigation

This error keeps coming in my development

Debug Console

```
[ERROR:flutter/lib/ui/ui_dart_state.cc(186)] Unhandled Exception: 'package:get_it/get_it_impl.dart': Failed assertion: line 312 pos 7: 'instanceFactory != null': Object/factory with  type NavigationService is not registered inside GetIt.
E/flutter (27190): (Did you accidentally do GetIt sl=GetIt.instance(); instead of GetIt sl=GetIt.instance;
E/flutter (27190): Did you forget to register it?)
```

This is the navigator service file in which the navigation service as well as getit is initialised

navigation_service.dart

```
GetIt locator = GetIt.instance;

setupLocator() {
  locator.registerLazySingleton(() => NavigationService());
}

class NavigationService {
  final GlobalKey<NavigatorState> navigatorKey = GlobalKey<NavigatorState>();
  Future<dynamic> navigateTo(routeName) {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pushReplacementNamed(routeName);
  }

  goBack() {
    return navigatorKey.currentState.pop();
  }
}
```

dynamic_link_service.dart

```
.
.
.
#some code

final NavigationService _navigationService = locator<NavigationService>();

if (deepLink != null) {
      // print('_handleDeepLink | deepLink: $deepLink');
      UserDataProvider().setReferralData(deepLink);
      _navigationService.navigateTo(ReferralSignupPage.routeName);
    }
.
.
.
```

main.dart

```
void main() async {
  WidgetsFlutterBinding.ensureInitialized();
  await setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
        debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
        home:
        .
        .
        .
        routes: {
          ReferralSignupPage.routeName: (ctx) => ReferralSignupPage(),
        },
        navigatorKey: locator<NavigationService>().navigatorKey,
      );
}
```

This error keeps coming even after having tried all the possible solutions provided in other questions
Please help me out of this.

Regards

Answer (score 0):

Just a guess here, but isn't the syntax:

```dart
final service = locator.get<NavigationService>();
```

Also possible you need to supply the generic parameter when registering the service.

Comment: Are you using the same global instance variable as the one you registered the service with? Since it’s saying it’s not registered, seem like another instance of the locator.

Answer (score -3):

add setupLocator();

```
void main() {
  setupLocator();
  runApp(MyApp());
}
```